# Objects of same class having varying selection of the class members (C++)

Tags: c++, class, oop

Let's say class A has members "int B" and "int C". When I create an object of this class, I would like to choose whether it will contain only "int B" or only "int C" (or maybe if it has them both).

*(I know that an alternative is declaring B and C as std::vectors and then resizing them to 1, but that means I'll have to add [0] after them each time I use them, and that also means I'll have to waste 20 bytes per member, because it seems that std::vector uses 20B by default, whether you assign anything to it or not.)*

Comment: What about inheritance?

Comment: Could you describe the problem you are trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: Reading any introductory text will tell you that this is not possible. But the important thing here is not the possibility of doing it or lack thereof. *What problem do you think you are going to solve by doing this?*

Comment: If objects have different properties, they belong per definition to different classes.

Comment: I would like to have a class called "Settlement", the objects of which will be villages and towns. However, I want only the towns to have a market and an industry.

Comment: class A virtual -> integer methods. class b implements those methods for 1 integer. Class c implements those methods for the other integer. class d, implements for both integers.

Comment: This is what inheritance had been invented for.

Comment: Inheritance means creating different classes, but I need only one.

Comment: why is one class a requirement?

Comment: Because I may need to pass through all the "Settlement" objects. I can make them of one array. But if I create two classes, one "Village", one "Town", I can't do a straight pass.

Comment: Yes, you can.  That's the point of inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Use inheritance.  You may need some virtual methods too.

```
class Settlement
{
   public:
      virtual void updateMarketCount()=0;//pure virtual function
};

class Town : public Settlement
{
    public:
       virtual void updateMarketCount();
    private:
       int m_markets;
       int m_industries;
};

class Village : public Settlement
{
     public:
       virtual void updateMarketCount();
     private:
       int m_markets;
};
```

This way you can assign all of these objects to a generic settlement pointer.  For example:

```
 std::shared_ptr<Settlement> mysettlementPtr(new Town());//C++ 11 only. Found in memory header
 Settlement* mysettlementPtr = new Town();//C++ < 11
```

Here is how to do a vector:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Settlement>> mySettlements;
mySettlements.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Town>(new Town()));
mySettlements.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Village>(new Village()));
```

**Here is a very simple working example:**

**Settlement.h:**

```
#pragma once
class Settlement
{
    public:
        virtual void increaseMarkets()=0;
        virtual int getMarketCount()=0;
};
```

**Town.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Settlement.h"
class Town : public Settlement
{
    public:
        Town():m_markets(0){}
        virtual void increaseMarkets(){++m_markets;}
        virtual int getMarketCount(){return m_markets;}
    private:
       int m_markets;
       int m_industries;
};
```

**Village.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Settlement.h"

class Village : public Settlement
{
    public:
        virtual void increaseMarkets(){++m_markets;}
        virtual int getMarketCount(){return m_markets;}
     private:
       int m_markets;
};
```

**SimpleExample.cpp:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#include "Settlement.h"
#include "Village.h"
#include "Town.h"

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Settlement> mysettlement(new Town());
    std::cout << "I HAVE: " << mysettlement->getMarketCount() << " MARKETS" <<  std::endl;
    mysettlement->increaseMarkets();
    std::cout << "NOW I HAVE " << mysettlement->getMarketCount() << " MARKETS" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE." << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** It is best to extract functions into .cpp files related to the headers.

Comment: Can you please give me a complete, running example of such a code? If I use it the way it is, and try to assign to mysettlement.m_markets a value, it results in error C2228: left of m_markets must have class/struct/union

Comment: I am really flattered by your effort, but the initial problem involves several objects. Can you please add to the code several objects, some of type Town, some of type Village, but all of them in a single array? Again, thank you for going this far.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

First, define 3 container classes that contain A, B or both.

```
class withA
{
  int varA;
};

class withB
{
  int varB;
};

class withAB
{
  int varA;
  int varB;
};
```

Next, define a template class, which is the class you want, and it contains this member variable, inside of which, there's A, B or A and B.

```
template<class T>
class theThing
{
   T m_thingMember;
};
```

Next, this is how you declare it.

```
theThing<withA> thingObjA;
theThing<withB> thingObjB;
theThing<withAB> thingObjAB;
```

Comment: It won't do it for me, because I want all of the objects to form one array, which excludes the possibility of several different declarations.

Comment: Then why not have a fixed-sized array of 2 integers and just use one of them at a time or both, instead of a vector?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't get your question.